# how to join asp.net mvc5 project with wpf project

Tags: wpf, asp.net-mvc-5

i have made two projects separately. one project is of windows presentation foundation type made in .net platform and second is in asp.net.
I want to join them in one solution.

anxiously waiting for your kind response

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual Studio Go to

> File->New->Project from Existing Code

select your project location give the name and select Finish.
It will create the new solution with that project.
Then right click on that solution Go to

> Add->Existing Project

then choose you project 
it will add two existing project into the single solution